# Linking Policies of copied Usecase in different space of IBM Blueworks Live?

Tags: business-process-management

I have created one Usecase and linked policies like BR and Error Msg to that Usecase. Then I copied that Usecase to another space.

My trouble is that the copied Usecase is linked to the policies of a different space.  How can I use policies in the same space and link to those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "Usecase" I assume you are talking about a Process Blueprint.

If you copy a Process Blueprint, only the process is copied. None of the linked assets like Policies are going to be copied with it, so the copy will point to the same Policy as the original.

If instead you want to create copies of everything, you can copy the space instead of just copying the process.  Assuming all the linked assets (i.e. Policies) are in the same space as your process, this will create copies of everything and the copy of your process will be correctly linked to the copy of the policies.

If all the assets are not in the same space, one workaround is to temporarily move the items you are wanting to copy into a temp space, copy that temp space and then move everything back to the original location.